# How to change values on y-axis for lattice xyplot

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I have an xy plot in lattice on which I'm showing four different things. The plot looks like this right now. The values for pink line range from 1 to 15000, however, values for other lines range from 20 to 300. This is why all lines other than pink seem static. However, there are fluctuations in them but I feel the graph isn't showing them property because of yaxis. Is there a way I can shorten the yaxis such that the graph is better representing the other lines as well?

[image]

This is how it looks when I don't plot the pink line all together. This shows there are fluctuations which I'd like to show.

[image]

Comment: It can be very misleading to have a discontinuous axis, precisely because the relative flatness of the three lower lines is obscured.

Comment: I would recommend that you make two graphs. One with the pink variable and one without, just as you have shown in your question.

You can show the two graphs at the same time, as long as the y-axis is visible and they're arranged vertically.

This way you can see the y-response for the different variables without misleading people who look at the graphs.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the base package instead of lattice it is quite simple. The code below is vastly simplified from one of my own plots. You will have to fiddle a little with it to add two more lines.

line      description

1,2  plot from a data frame. ylab will be on side 2 (left) scale will be automatically determined from the data

3    start a second plot

4    plot from a data frame, use axes=FALSE, xlab=NA, ylab=NA

5    create the axis for side 4 (right) scale will be automatically determined from the data

6    make the ylab for side 4

```
 1  plot(df[c(4,5)], type = "s", col = "blue", main = "Battery Life",
 2      xlab="minutes", ylab="percent")
 3  par(new=TRUE)
 4  plot(df[c(4,6)], type = "s", col = "red", axes = FALSE, xlab = NA, ylab = NA)
 5  axis(side = 4)
 6  mtext(side = 4, line = 3, "Slope ( minutes)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the latticeExtra package to create a graph with 2 separate y-axis.

As the comments suggest, I would rather create 2 separate plots. It's a cleaner solution.

As an alternativ: maybe you could add a conditioning variable to your data ("magnitude" or so) which groups your data into suitable chunks. Then you could present your data as shown below.

```
library("lattice")
library("latticeExtra")

dat1 <- data.frame(x=1:100, y1=rep(1:10,10), y2=rep(100:91,10))

dat2 <- data.frame(x=1:200, y=c(rep(1:10,10), rep(100:91,10)), 
               z=c(rep("small",100), rep("huge",100)))

p1 <- xyplot(y1~x, data=dat1, type="l")

p2 <- xyplot(y2~x, data=dat1, type="l")

doubleYScale(p1, p2) # 2 y-axis: bad

xyplot(y ~ x | z, data=dat2, type="l", scales="free") # 2 plots: good
```